# Jenkins GitLab Merge Request Remote Commit Reference

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, continuous-integration, gitlab

I have added the GitLab plugin to jenkins and set a webhook so GitLab triggers a Jenkins build. Jenkins pulls the revision and merges it locally with the target branch. Afterwards it builds the merged code. So far everything is fine.

Now I want Sonarqube to analyse the merged code and add comments to the GitLab merge request (using the Sonarqube GitLab plugin). For this I would need the remote commit SHA from Jenkins to be passed into Sonarqube as sonar.gitlab.commit_sha

However in Jenkins in this case the variable $GIT_COMMIT refers to the locally created merge commit - which of course cannot be found in GitLab and therefore no comment can be added.

Is there any solution to this? Am I on the wrong track doing it this way and should I just provide the sonarqube comments for pushes to the feature branches (before the merge request)?

Thanks for any input.